# Лаги при скроллинга ListView

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

У меня макет тяжелый, и выглядит так:

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesList}"
                   HasUnevenRows="true"
                   SeparatorVisibility="None"
                   ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="5">
                                            <Frame  Padding="10, 10, 10, 10" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="10" >
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Image HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="50"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Source="{Binding Image} " />
                                                        <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                        <Label  VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Detail}" TextColor="Black" />
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="1000" />
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                        <ff:CachedImage DownsampleToViewSize="true"  BitmapOptimizations="True" CacheType="Disk" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="40"  Source="{Binding Image_Like} ">
                                                            <ff:CachedImage.Transformations>

                                                            </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                                        </ff:CachedImage>
                                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Padding="1, 6, 5, 0"  Text="{Binding LikeCount}" />
                                                        <ff:CachedImage DownsampleToViewSize="true" BitmapOptimizations="True" CacheType="Disk" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="40"  Source="{Binding Image_Comment} " />
                                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Padding="1, 6, 5 , 0" Text="{Binding CommentCount}" />
                                                        <ff:CachedImage DownsampleToViewSize="true" BitmapOptimizations="True" CacheType="Disk" WidthRequest="23" HeightRequest="40"  Source="{Binding Image_Share} " />
                                                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Padding="1, 6, 5 , 0" Text="{Binding ShareCount}" />
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

При 20 макетов при скроллинга начинает жестко лагать. Будто там пытаешься успеть подгружать следующий макет. Использовал кэшинг RetainElement. Не помогло. Начал гуглить, что он лагает из за изображение. Начал менять его на FFImageLoading ( **ff - FFImageLoading** ) Не помогло. Все равно лаги при скроллинга.

Я любой способ пробовал. Пробовал GlideX - Лагает. Пробовал FastView - лагает. Предложили попробовать GitTrends, но у них приложуха даже при скроллинга лагает

Comment: может быть Вы пытаетесь подгружать слишком большие изображения?

Comment: Я что-то не подумал об этом. Щас попробую сжать изображение